# Оптимизация запроса c кучей join-ов, Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня супер кул расчудесный запрос )

Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать. Схемы таблиц не смогу привести. Но надеюсь на глаз кто может разобраться.

```
    SELECT p.id AS id, p.id_1c AS id_1c, pfvComb.catId AS category, s.frame_id AS frame, s.color_id AS color, pfvComb.gender AS genderCode, pfvComb.wheel AS wheel, pp.name AS picture
FROM products AS p
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT pfv.product_id, pfv.feature_code AS categoryCode, pfv.value_integer AS catId, pfv_g.value_integer AS gender, pfv_w.value_integer AS wheel
              FROM products_features_values AS pfv
                LEFT JOIN products_features_values AS pfv_g
                  ON pfv.product_id = pfv_g.product_id AND pfv_g.feature_code = 'gender'
                LEFT JOIN products_features_values AS pfv_w
                  ON pfv.product_id = pfv_w.product_id AND pfv_w.feature_code = 'wheel'
              WHERE pfv.feature_code IS NOT NULL AND pfv.feature_code = 'category' AND pfv.value_integer = 10
            ) AS pfvComb ON p.id = pfvComb.product_id
  LEFT JOIN sku AS s ON p.id = s.product_id
  LEFT JOIN products_pictures AS pp ON p.id = pp.product_id
WHERE p.is_visible = 1 AND p.is_valid = 1
ORDER BY p.popularity DESC
```

Такой запрос выполняется, но тяжело. Как его можно оптимизировать?

Comment: По моему, на глаз тут не разобраться. Чтобы  нормально оптимизировать запрос надо видеть структуру таблиц, план запроса и обладать статистикой по содержимому таблиц. И при этом надо понимать, задачу которую вы выполняете.

Comment: @Viktorov да, вы правы. И на что я надеялся?

Comment: Начните оптимизацию с понимания, нахрена нужно задание порядка объединения... когда оно придёт - ищите понимание, везде ли нужно левое связывание... затем определите наиболее разумный порядок связывания таблиц... и наконец определите и создайте необходимые индексы.

Comment: Здесь действительно без описания логики таблиц и без приведения их структуры сложно что-то сделать, т.к. в самом худшем случае этот запрос и есть оптимальный уже. Если во внутреннем запросе можно переделать без потери смысла LEFT JOIN на INNER, и само подклеивание этого подзапроса тоже, то тогда можно все внутренние JOIN-ы вынести просто. С другой стороны, я вот не очень понимаю для чего вообще такой странный подзапрос - Вы ничего не группируете, не упорядочиваете... там записи 1 к 1? или 1 ко многим? или наоборот?